# How to prove or disprove that all linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ have a real eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that not all linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ have a real eigenvalue. However, in my intuition, it seems like all linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ have an real eigenvalue. I'm not sure how to prove it or find a counterexample, though. Could you help me?

Comment: the characteristic polynomial has degree $3$ and hence a root.

Comment: A polynomial of odd degree with real coefficients has a real root.